# Quais frameworks PHP tem melhor suporte para trabalhar com bancos de dados NoSQL?

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql, cassandra

Eu gostaria de saber quais frameworks PHP tem melhor suporte para trabalhar com bancos de dados NoSQL?

Os bancos NoSQL que já tenho experiência são MongoDB, Redis e Cassandra, mas tenho interesse em testar outras opções como LevelDB MemCache e HBase. No entanto as opções com as quais já trabalhei não possuem suporte muito bom implementado nos frameworks PHP mais modernos que costumo utilizar como Laravel 5 e ZF2.

Alguém trabalhando com outros frameworks onde o trabalho de configuração dos drivers para trabalhar com estes banco dados seja um processo mais natural? E que tenha uma implementação de ODM semelhante ao mongoose utilizado com o node para realizar consultas mas que seja extensível ao framework estilo o estilo o ORM Eloquent no Laravel?

Talvez se não houver um projeto semelhante deveríamos começar a movimentar uma comunidade em torno de um projeto voltado a esta necessidade.

Comment: Quanto ao Redis, você pode usar o Predis, quanto a frameworks PHP, acredito que o ReactPHP é o que dá melhor suporte às novas tecnologias Web.

Comment: Eu conheço e já testei no Framework Laravel, funciona muito bem, que na verdade é um pacote que pode ser instalado em qualquer framework que utilize o gerenciador de pacotes ou pode ser instalado fora do framework também funciona.

Comment: Virgilio eu não entendi bem, você está se referindo à que exatamente? Você já testou MongoDB com Laravel? é isso? Qual pacote você utilizou?

Comment: Teria sido este? https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enquanto elaborava a pergunta encontrei na documentação oficial do MongoDB uma referência das libraries PHP para trabalhar com Mongo, respondendo parte de meus questionamentos

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php-libraries/

Vou pesquisar referências de outros bancos e verificar se já existe algum projeto que implemente o driver de bancos NoSQL configurável estilo o DB Diver do Laravel onde a escolha do database fica transparente (no caso de DB relacional).